# Why I can't make a call with Telegram?

Tags: calls, telegram

Every time I try to call,it write "Waiting" and then "Failed to connect".
I cant make a call.

How fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear cache and data of the app through `Settings > Apps and notifications > See all > Telegram > Storage and cache > Clear (for both)`
Check also the permissions (on the same menu of "Storage and cache") and make sure Telegram can access Phone.

Comment: it seems when person which I call is at wifi ,then call is ok but if he is at mobile data then failed to connect...really strange bug